# How to understand `each time to you hit a page`?

Tags: adjectives

A sentence in http://www.cs.montana.edu/~tosun/phpvsjava.pdf page 2:

```
Even Administrator chroots  (each time to you hit a page) for security.
```

The `to` adjectives here confused me ,why don't omit it ?

```
Even Administrator chroots  (each time  you hit a page) for security.
```

Or write it as :

```
Even Administrator chroots  (each time when you hit a page) for security.
```

Comment: Using "to" is a grammar error. I noticed several grammar errors in this document. Perhaps the author is not a native English speaker?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear after user3169's comment, your second example sentence is the best choice of the three.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by user3169 and user8399, the document that you reference has numerous grammar errors.

As a matter of fact, the line in question looks like it might have originally been attached to the compound bullet point preceding it and the author simply made it into its own bullet point without writing it as a single, complete sentence.